# Drawing offscreen WebView and capturePicture issues

Tags: android, bitmap, webview

My goal is to turn a WebView into a Bitmap so I can add it to a homescreen widget. I have gotten WebView.capturePicture() to work fine; however, I cannot get the WebView to render without setting it as the content layout or similar. As this is an app widget I won't be able to set it as a view.

Is it possible to render a WebView and save it to a bitmap without setting it as the content view?

Comment: From what I found, this is not possible.

Comment: This post will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633988/generate-bitmap-from-html-in-android

Comment: Thanks, this won't work because it requires the webview to be rendered on screen.