# Convert HTML to image (any format) on Android

Tags: android, html, image

Does anyone know how to convert html code (with images within it) to image on Android? I know how to make it on Java using JLabel/JEditorPane and BufferedImage, but now should make the same with Android.

Comment: I think this is good solution: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163202/convert-html-and-set-text-to-textview/12703962#12703962](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163202/convert-html-and-set-text-to-textview/12703962#12703962)

Comment: Hi peter. Did you found any solution for this? I need exactly the same you asked..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate bitmap from HTML in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633988/generate-bitmap-from-html-in-android)

Answer (score 7):

The answer of @Neo1975 is worked for me, but to avoid using **deprecated** method `WebView.capturePicture()` you could use the following method to capture content of WebView.

```
/**
* WevView screenshot
*
* @param webView
* @return
*/
private static Bitmap screenshot(WebView webView) {
  webView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    webView.layout(0, 0, webView.getMeasuredWidth(), 
    webView.getMeasuredHeight());
    webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getMeasuredWidth(), 
    webView.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    int iHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, iHeight, paint);
    webView.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

The idea behind it is using `WebView.draw(Canvas)` method.

Answer (score 5):

For this task I use the follow trick:
I used a webview to parse HTML and call the method capturePicture on WevView object to extract a Picture of HTML, so I can suggest you the follow sniplet:

```
WebView wv = new WebView(this);
wv.loadData("<html><body><p>Hello World</p></body></html>");
Picture p = wv.capturePicture();
```

I hope this can help, but if you foun a different way to solve it please post it.

Comment: Hi, can u tell me how to save this picture in sd card ? @Neo

Comment: @koti That could be a different question.

Comment: this function is deprecated, what is the Alternative?