# Convert Html and Set text to Textview

Tags: android, html

I am trying to convert a html String and set it to a TextView but I couldn't do it exactly.

Here is my String, **"Hello, %1$s! You have <b>%2$d new messages</b>"**

I am using **textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(myString));** which produces me an output with Html Tags instead of plain text. Can anyone help me with this?

Any help is much appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.TextView.BufferType%29) version of setText and use SPANNABLE buffer type

Answer (score 15):

Refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730706/highlighting-text-color-using-html-fromhtml-in-android).

try:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myString), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 7):

This may be helpful to you:

```
Spanned marked_up = Html.fromHtml(myString);
textview.setText(marked_up.toString(),BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but extend TextView and override SetText like so:

```
public override void SetText(ICharSequence text, BufferType type)
{
    base.SetText(Html.FromHtml(text.ToString()), BufferType.Spannable);
}
```

Then you can just use your TextView instead of the regular one in your axml.

Answer (score 0):

even later...
Html.fromHtml is deprecated now:

```
textView.setText(
    Html.fromHtml(model.getValue(), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT), 
    TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT worked well for me, explore the other flags for different HTML parsing behaviour.